# If $x^{1008}y^{1006}=(x+y)^{2014}$, then $\,\,\frac{dy}{dx}\,\,$ is which of the following:

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am stuck on the following problem that says:

> If $x^{1008}y^{1006}=(x+y)^{2014}$, then $\,\,\frac{dy}{dx}\,\,$ is which of the following:
>
> 1. $\frac xy$
> 2. $\frac{y}{x+y}$
> 3. $\frac{y}{x}$
> 4. $\frac{2014}{x+y}$

What I have got is : $x^{1008}y^{1006}=(x+y)^{2014}\implies 1=(1+\frac yx)^{1008}(1+\frac xy)^{1006}$. The problem is the question bears only 1 marks and I can not find the trick to tackle it easily. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I think taking logarithm on both sides will do the trick.

$$\ln (x^{1008}y^{1006})=\ln (x+y)^{2014} \\ \implies 1008 \ln(x)+1006\ln(y)=2014 \ln(x+y)$$ and from it we can ultimately reach $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac yx$.

Any better idea than it for a multiple choice question like it ????

Comment: Good idea. $~~~$